# TypeError: randint() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)

Tags: python, python-2.7, random

```
import random
List1 = ['I am a ', 'You are a ']
List2 = ['man', 'woman', 'duck']
L1 = random.randint(List1)
L2 = random.randint(List2)
print L1 + L2
```

I am trying to make a random sentence generator, but instead got an error:
TypeError: randint() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)

Comment: Did you read the documentation for the `random.randint()` function yet? The function does **not** accept a list of values, and your attempt to use it that way is rather non-sensical. Perhaps you were looking for `random.choice()` instead?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thank you for the help :) No, I haven't read the documentation yet, and I am obviously very new to python. The code works now. Again, thank you!

Comment: It would be much more productive if you did first look for the documentation of functions you use, and *share your research* if that doesn't solve your issue when you do eventually post here.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Will definitely do it next time!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using random.randint()', you should use 'random.choice()', like so:

```
L1 = random.choice(List1)
L2 = random.choice(List2)
```

Comment: Thank you :) It works now. Sorry for the nooby question!